# Why am I getting a 403 error on localhost on this css link that has import statements?

Tags: jquery, css, import, http-status-code-403

Why am I getting a 403 error on localhost on this link?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cookies.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    THE FOLLOWING LINE CAUSES A 403 ERROR
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" /> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../development-bundle/demos/demos.css" />
```

In desperation, I changed the permissions of everything leading to jquery.ui.all.css to 755 which did not resolve the problem.

These are the contents of jquery.ui.all.css:

```
@import "jquery.ui.base.css";
@import "jquery.ui.theme.css";
```

Any link I add that has an import statement gives me a 403 error. I spent several hours searching for an answer but no luck.  Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy. One of these directories doen't have permissions (apache2) or that css file has no permission to be opened with apache2

0755 are correct permissions

Comment: `I had changed all the directories and files leading to that file but not all of the other files. When I changed everything to 755, the 403 error disappeared.` 

`What is confusing me is that the other files such as:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cookies.js"> </script>`

`have this for permissions: -rw-r--r-- and works without any problems. What is it about the link and import statements that requires the 755 permission?`

Answer (score 2):

I performed following steps

Change the owner and/or group of each FILE to OWNER and/or GROUP.
OWNER being the one with which you started the server.

```
chown -R <user> /var/www/html/
```

When you do - chown --help, one can find the possible usages.

Next, Change permission of the file

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/
```

Note
-R = recursively applies it to all folders/files within directory

403 error will be resolved.

As mentioned in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/proper-permissions-for-web-server-s-directory

Comment: I could only think of a single good way of mentioning `root` and `/var/www/` in the same sentence: One should never use **root** for anything inside **/var/www/**.

Comment: Yes, in 99.9% cases all files and folders in /var/www/ must be owned by the same user under which you run your webserver. Usually it is one of the following: apache2, nginx or www-data. Also check carefully what permissions you set for your data - it is easy to expose your server to various attack by setting up a wrong permissions. Here's some more info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/proper-permissions-for-web-server-s-directory

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. Updated my answer accordingly. Does this help?